# How do I match a string that is not preceeded by a character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings and I need to perform a search and replace on them using JavaScript.  The issue is they only need to be found when they are not preceeded by one of two characters.  What I have tried is:

```
 var searchString = new RegExp( "(?<![#\|])" + tableName,"");
 if(theLine.search(searchString) != -1){do something;}
```

tableName is variable and changes for each call based on data retreived from a database.

If tableName is Fred, I want to find Fred but not #Fred or |Fred.

What I have doesn't work and I'm not sure why.  It's probably a simple goof but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = 'If tableName is Fred, I want to find Fred but not #Fred or |Fred';
s.match(/[^#\|]Fred/g)
[" Fred", " Fred"]
```

Though my answer contains an Extra Space. You need to do is

```
var s = 'If tableName is Fred, I want to find TFred Fred but not #Fred or |Fred';

var replaceWith = "XXXX";
s.replace(/[^#\|]Fred/g, function($1) {
    if($1 != $1.trim()) {
        return " " + replaceWith;
    } else {
        return replaceWith;
    }
})

//output - "If tableName is XXXX, I want to find XXXX XXXX but not #Fred or |Fred"
```

Comment: The regex works.  Thanks.  The function($1){} doesn't work.  I suspect it works in a browser but not just running it as a script.  I'm not sure how the $1 would be populated.  It's a cludge but I can live with adding a " " to the front of the replace text.

Comment: Thanks for trusting on a cludge. How $1 gets populated? - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1742-using-regular-expressions-in-javascript-a-general-overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds**. But you can do something like this regex to overcome that issue:

```
var s = 'If tableName is Fred, I want to find Fred but not #Fred or |Fred';
var r = s.replace(/([#|]Fred)|Fred/g, '$1')
//=> If tableName is , I want to find  but not #Fred or |Fred
```

Comment: "doesn't support lookbehinds"  That explains why it looked good but wouldn't work.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
var searchString = new RegExp("(?<![^\|\#])" + tableName,"");
if (theLine.search(searchString) != -1){do something;}
```

You forgot to negate the character range that you don't want it to match on.

Comment: `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind, which means "if not preceded by...". There's no need to negate the character class. JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, so this is not going to work anyway.

Comment: Crap, I completely forgot that.